# How to change two alternative file extension with a specific extension?

Tags: bash, text-processing, filenames

I have two different file extensions `abc.fq.gz` and `abc.fastq.gz` and I need to change these to `abc.sam`.

I tried this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
refdir="Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna_sm.primary_assembly"
forward=(*_1.{fq,fastq}.gz)
reverse=(*_2.{fq,fastq}.gz)

for i in "${!forward[@]}"
do
  echo ${forward[i]//_1.{fq,fastq}.gz/.sam}>> a.txt
done
```

but this `{fq,fastq}` part doesn't work. As you can see above I need to replace either `_1.fq.gz` or `_2.fastq.gz` with `.sam`, so

- the input is either `abc_1.fq.gz` or `abc_1.fastq.gz`
- and the expected output is `abc.sam`

How can I do this?

Comment: Please edit your question and be more specific when you say "doesn't work". **What** doesn't work as you expect it to? What is your expected result? Please include examples of input and output data by editing.

Comment: You cannot use brace expansion inside variable substitution. Generally, your approach has several issues, e.g. you should not parse `ls`.

Comment: Won't you end up clobbering a file if you try to rename both `abc.fq.gz` and `abc.fastq.gz` to `abc.sam`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller No it won't be a problem. I just need to change these names. I will give these names as a parameter to a software to change the file types. And fq and fastq formats are actually the same.

Comment: a bit beside your question, but a) `$(ls *.foo)` is a bit silly, it's the shell that expands the pattern and `ls` just basically gets filenames from the command line and prints them. And you get issues with word splitting too. Just `array=(*.foo)` would work, and would work better. b) You could do just `for f in "${array[@]}"; do...` to loop over the values, no need to go throgugh the index in the loop. Unless the idea is that the elements in `forward` and `reverse` arrays match each other at each index, but that's a risky assumption: if even one file is missing, the whole list will be off.

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks for the warning about ls. I fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use brace expansion inside a bash parameter expansion, however you can use KSH-style extended globs. Ex.

```
touch foo_1.fq.gz bar_1.fastq.gz

shopt -s nullglob extglob

forward=( *_1.{fq,fastq}.gz )
```

Notes:

1. add `nullglob` to prevent unmatched globs from being added to the array
2. don't use `ls` to populate the array - see [bash pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Then

```
$ for i in ${!forward[@]}; do echo "${forward[i]/_1.@(fq|fastq).gz/.sam}"; done
foo.sam
bar.sam
```

Comment: Can you please explain `shopt -s nullglob extglob` part, please. What does that part do?

Comment: @BaranAldemir `shopt extglob` is required to support the `@(fq|fastq)` syntax, while `shopt nullglob` prevents literal `*_1.fq.gz` or `*_1.fastq.gz` from being included in the results if they don't match anything.